# Jenkins plus Git on same server

Tags: git, jenkins

I have home server with git repositories.
Now I'm trying to configure Jenkins over existing PHP repos.

I've install Jenkins normally but I'm getting the error while creating the Job:

> Repository URL = /home/git/repositories/testing.git

Error is following:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h
>   /home/git/repositories/testing.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
>   stdout:  stderr: fatal: '/home/git/repositories/testing.git' does not
>   appear to be a git repository fatal: The remote end hung up
>   unexpectedly

Please help to resolve this problem.

Thank you.

P.S. I even tries to put URL that I'm using to clone repo remotely:

> ssh://git@192.168.1.110:/testing.git

But I'm still getting error:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h
>   ssh://git@192.168.1.110:/testing.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
>   stdout:  stderr: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.1.110:: Name
>   or service not known  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem:

1) put private key in .ssh for jenkins user

2) set Manage Credentials in Jenkins to access .ssh folder

Answer (score 2):

First issue, if jenkins is installed on the same machine, and testing.git is visibile, check your URL path. You won't see the red warning message if the repo is reachable.

Only thing i can think of is `/home/git` might be on a different server/mount point (maybe NAS?)

---

Second issue, cloning using SSH - remove the `:` (colon) after the IP address and make sure you give full path to repo

Comment: For the first issue I believe the problem with granting. But I've already add jenkins user to git group.

The second issue need to be checked. I will put the results asap.

Comment: After removing excessive ":" I got
`Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h ssh://git@192.168.1.110/testing.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory 
Permission denied, please try again. 
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory 
Permission denied, please try again. 
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory 
Permission denied (publickey,password). 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: And another one: `Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h ssh://git@localhost/testing.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory 
Host key verification failed. 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: Maybe "Manage Credentials" can help?