# Jenkins fails to connect to git repository

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to connect Jenkins to my git repository (not GitHub). Jenkins returns the following message:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@localhost/~/shoppinglist HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: 'git@localhost/~/shoppinglist' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The URL I'm providing is:

```
git@localhost/~/shoppinglist
```

If I run the command `git ls-remote -h git@localhost/~/shoppinglist HEAD` on the console with the jenkins user, it doesn't throw any errors (or any output). I specify the password with credentials, "Username with password", username: git, password: my password.

Comment: Don't you need to specify a protocol with your url?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no, it's not necesary. I tried with the ssh:// protocol too. Same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jenkins plus Git on same server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775054/jenkins-plus-git-on-same-server)

Comment: @Howlin yes, looks very much like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try :-

1) put private key in .ssh for jenkins user

2) set Manage Credentials in Jenkins to access .ssh folder

As described in [Jenkins plus Git on same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775054/jenkins-plus-git-on-same-server)